# Movie about aliens attacking young adults after they start taking down metal that was hung all around the house

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

A young man inherits a farm house. His friends come to help him settle in. They start experiencing attacks as they remove pieces of metal hung around the outside of the house. The aliens portal into the house and, in one scene, this cuts one of the guys in half.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and when do you think it might've been made? Also, can you describe the appearance of the aliens?

Comment: Watch it in the 90s. Not sure year it was made. Al

Comment: Aliens were typical "greys" with a mean attitude

Comment: So the film you're looking for isn't _Silent Warnings_ (2003)...?

Answer (score 3):

Might this be ***[Silent Warnings](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0348031/)*** (2003)...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_Warnings):

> *Silent Warnings* (also known as *Dark Harvest*) is a 2003 science fiction/horror television film about a group of college students who begin finding crop circles by the house they have moved into. Following the disappearance of one of them, they begin suspecting something sinister. It was commissioned by Syfy (then known as Sci-Fi Channel), written and directed Christian McIntire, and stars Stephen Baldwin, A. J. Buckley and Billy Zane. The project was released on DVD as *Warnings* by WL on June 23, 2003 and as *Silent Warnings* by Universal on August 26, 2003.

> **After his cousin Joe (Stephen Baldwin) dies, Layne Vassimer (A. J. Buckley) and his girlfriend Macy (Callie De Fabry), along with their friends Stephen (David O'Donnell), Maurice (Ransford Doherty), Iris (Kim Onasch) and Katrina (Michelle Borth), decide to clean up Joe's house with the intention of selling it. When they see it for the first time, they discover the house completely covered in plates of iron armor.**
>
> The group also finds crop circles in the nearby cornfield. When Iris suddenly disappears, they realize something is really wrong. **During a blackout, the house is attacked by aliens. The group figures out the aliens are allergic to iron, which is why Joe had covered the house in it to keep them out.** They attempt to fight the aliens off, but the house is eventually blown up with Layne, Macy, and Katrina the only survivors.
>
> In the end, they drive off, listening to the radio. They hear a news report stating that the blackout they experienced affects five western states and parts of Canada. They also hear that people everywhere are being attacked by "strange creatures."

From a [review](https://beckoningchasm.com/words/silentwarnings.html):

> They decide to board up the windows. While they're busy at that, Dark-Hair and Steven clinch, then another purple light appears and **an alien materializes in the middle of the room! Steven rushes it with a fire poker (made of iron), but it ducks, and a circular pattern appears on the floor, with both alien and Steven inside. Everything starts to fade, and Steven reaches outside the circle...and when it disappears, he seems to be cut in half.**